# How can I merge tags?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Not sure whether this is a bug or a reputation level problem, but I noticed that there's a tag "filter" and a tag "filters", which I suggest should be merged to "filters". However, all tag modifications are read-only for me.

Comment: I suggest that if it's a reputation level problem, that it must be a bug.  If the [privileges](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/privileges) prevent us from presenting a good beta site, then they need to be changed.  You're the 15th highest-rep user, you ought to be able to do almost everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to simply retag the applicable questions. There are only three of them...

On beta sites, [you need 1250 reputation points](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) to create tag synonyms. Since it'll be a little bit before anyone hits that, you can just ask a moderator (by posting here on meta) to set one up for you when needed.

I've done [filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) -> [filters](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters) for you.

Comment: Also flags. Why does everyone run to meta instead of flagging. :p (yes yes, three whole Qs)

Comment: @jco: yes, if it's an obvious merge/synonym flagging works... But flagging prevents any community discussion, which is rather nice for merge suggestions that *aren't* simple pluralization deals.

Comment: Touche good sir