# Two tags for SDR. Why not merge them?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

Signal Processing SE has tags [sdr](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdr) and [software-defined-radio](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-defined-radio). Why not [merge](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31/21075) them?

Answer (score 3):

You're right, these are synonymous.

I've created a [synonym suggestion](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tags/software-defined-radio/synonyms), and users with a few answers on the tag can vote for it.

I believe since this is really just a matter of expanding an acronym, a moderator might be able to expedite the process.

Comment: Hi! I think SDR sounds more like an abbreviation than an acronym (such as radar, sonar, lidar, codec, modem etc.) DSP, KGB, FBI, and CIA are examples of abbreviations (specifically in the form of *initialism*)