# Two tags for compressed sensing. Why not merge them?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging, retagging

We have tags [compressed-sensing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compressed-sensing) and [compressive-sensing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compressive-sensing). Why not [merge](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31/21075) them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merged <kbd>compressed-sensing</kbd> onto <kbd>compressive-sensing</kbd> because there are many more <kbd>compressive-sensing</kbd> than <kbd>compressed-sensing</kbd> questions (88 vs 16) and all 16 <kbd>compressed-sensing</kbd> are double-tagged with <kbd>compressive-sensing</kbd>.

Also made <kbd>compressed-sensing</kbd> a synonym of <kbd>compressive-sensing</kbd>, it shouldn't reappear.

[image: Add]